# CPU and/or Memory intensive algorithms

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement some simple JavaScript algorithms that cause high cpu/memory usage without displaying anything. Would create additional threads with Web Workers do the trick ? Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Threads won´t decrease the total CPU load (same for memory). If the algorithm needs that much, it needs that much, nothing else to say. Choosing something else other than JS and maybe optimizing your code would help.

Comment: Probably my question was odd enough to cause misunderstanding. I don't want to implement anything in particular, I DO want the system to be slowed down/frozen

Comment: Luckily, with JS you don´t have the freedom of C or similar. And vote for close, because this sounds of scriptkiddie-malware.

Comment: I'm afraid I've the possibility to give you plenty of documentation this is not about me poorly trying to create some malware to impress my friends, but it is part of larger analysis I'm conducting. If you are not able to give any serious answer to my question, even if I admit it may look strange, I would politely invite you to spend your time bothering someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities:

1. Web Workers (CPU based threads) [1]
2. WebCL (Use of GPU) "provides JavaScript bindings to OpenCL APIs for use by HTML5 web-bowsers"

WebCL 1.0 has just been released (19th of March 2014) [2]

[1]   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker

[2]   http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTYzNTk

Answer (score 0):

Web Workers would off load the CPU intensive task to a background thread. This will free up the UI thread and make for a better user experience. I recently used web workers on a pretty intensive task that took 7 seconds to run. With out web workers the page would be frozen and sometimes throw a long running script error. With web workers the process still takes 7 seconds but the page doesn't freeze which allows me to do other things while its doing some processing.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to freeze the UI thread or throw errors, I just need to significantly decrease system resources so that I can notice the performance difference when the task is not running.